# How do I enable mod_Gzip on Apache 2.2.17?

Tags: windows, apache, gzip

I'm working on windows7 64bit env.How should I enable gzip module on apache 2.2.17?
And what are differences between mod_deflate and mod_gzip?
thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can enable it like this in your apache config file, or .htaccess file if enabled

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json
</IfModule>
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Answer (score 9):

There is no `mod_gzip` for Apache 2.2x, as it is an Apache 1.3x module. Apache 2.2x has a only `mod_deflate`. GZip is the same DEFLATE plus a checksum and header/footer. As you can [see here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/youre-reading-the-worlds-most-dangerous-programming-blog.html), Deflate is faster.

Answer (score 9):

mod_deflate module is shipped with Apache, but in order to use it, you should enable one in your `httpd.conf` file (it is initially commented out):

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

After that just add following to the `httpd.conf`:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
```

For more tuning refer, as was mentioned:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Answer (score 6):

Also note that mod_filter needs to be loaded as well as mod_deflate (due to both being commented out by default):

```
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

Like the previous comment:
After that just add following to the httpd.conf:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
```

Tested on: Apache/2.4.10

Note: mod_filter is required in 2.4, although in 2.2 that may not be the case.

Comment: Thanks! A disabled filter_module was my problem in Apache 2.4.